# Get size of movie file in Python

Tags: python

How would I get the size of a .mov file in Python. With other files, I can do:

```
>>> f = open('<file>')
>>> import os
>>> os.path.getsize(f.read())
```

However, when I try and do this with a .mov file, I get the following error:

```
>>> os.path.getsize(f.read())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File     "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/genericpath.py", line 49, in getsize
    return os.stat(filename).st_size
TypeError: stat() argument 1 must be (encoded string without NULL bytes), not str
```

What is causing this error and how would I get the filesize?

Comment: does `os.path.getsize("<file>")` work?

Comment: With a file object, you could seek to the end of the file and use `tell()` to get the current position (i.e., length).  Though I don't know how reliable that is.

Comment: Why don#t you just check the documentation of os.path.getsize() in order to figure out that it requires a filename?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. `os.path.getsize` takes a file name, not file contents. I have no idea why your first code sample works.

So you need to call just `os.path.getsize(<file>)`.

Comment: proboably, because the content of the file is a valid filename :)

Answer (score 4):

Try the following:

```
os.path.getsize(FILENAME_AS_STRING)
```